# Selecting named range from dropdown list in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have several ranges that may need sorting. I want to use a range name selected from a dropdown list to select and sort that range:

```
Sub Sorts()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As String

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Products")
    Set rng = Ws1.Range("G76").Value


    Ws1.Range("rng").Sort Range("rng").Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

macro stops at St rng .......object required

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, apart for a little detail. 
The right line of code should be this one:

```
Ws1.Range(rng).Sort Range(rng).Cells(1, 1)
```

This is due to the difference between *variables* and *strings*. Your `rng` is a *variable* of type string; it means that it's a string, but it contains a specific `value` that you have "almost" correctly referenced here (you don't need the `Set` keyword for a string:

```
rng = Ws1.Range("G76").Value
```

However, if you pass the variable `rng` with quotes `""`, VBA will understand that has to look for a range named exactly `rng`; which, apparently, doesn't exist so you get an object not-set error.

Comment: It now does what I hoped it would do and I'm a bit wiser. You're a star. Thanks for your time.